# Unable to resign resignFirstResponder on UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
    self.searchbar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 50)];
    self.searchbar.delegate = self;
    UITextField *field = (UITextField *)[[[self.searchbar.subviews firstObject] subviews] lastObject];
    field.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
    field.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    [self.view addSubview:self.searchbar];

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if (searchText.length == 0) {
        [self.searchbar resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

I'm sure the search bar delegate has gone; if I delete characters one by one, it will `resignFirstResponder`, but if I press the symbol 'x', it also will come in this method, but it will not `resignFirstResponder`. Why is this happening?

Comment: Try `[self.view endEditing:YES];`

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that your problem is only when tapping the little "x" icon to clear the search bar, correct? And in this case, the `textDidChange` method is still be called, correct? In that case, is the `if` statement true or not?

Comment: [self.view endEditing:YES]; this method does not work.
And the if statement will come in.